# The Enderman is completely passive

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I play Minecraft 1.14 in Hardcore Mode. I provoked an Enderman, so in the first place he tried to attack me, but then I ran away from him, but I wasn't running or looking back. Using the third person camera I could see he was still angry, but just following me without attacking me. So I continued to walk to the sea and got in to protect myself. He stayed on the ground, but was not angry anymore. He just teleported a lot near me, and took blocks. Now I can look at him, attack him, but he doesn't become angry at all, and won't attack me.

I really don't understand why. Is this a new feature in 1.14? Or normal behaviour?
The Enderman used to follow and fight to the death.

I searched the internet, but I couldn't find any similar situation, so I'm guessing it could be related to the update.

I have multiple screenshots of the situation, and my game is still paused in this situation.

Comment: No idea why this happens, but it's not only endermen. I remember that in 1.13 and also in 1.14 I can walk right up to a creeper or zombie in survival without them attacking, but if I hit them they get angry and attack me. I mean really close, like 2 or 3 blocks away. Doesn't really happen with skeletons or other mobs as far as I've noticed, and only rarely happens with spiders. I haven't experienced the passivity thing, but it is interesting behavior. I think it's probably a bug in the AI.

Comment: For me, a zombie has attacked me the same time that the Endermen went passive. And the endermen NEVER get angry, i can push him, hit him, take selfies, he doesn't open his mouth. He just teleport like 32 block away several times and finish to come back to me. He doesn't follow me, he just teleport near of me. In first place i was thinking it's a new mechanic of the Endermen

Comment: Does he still shake with an open mouth? Then he might be angry at the dragon.

Comment: @Fabian wxi mentioned a sea so I think it is in the over world.

Comment: Then it might have been a creeper that exploded far enough away to not kill it, but close enough to damage it or a witch that threw a damage potion near it or anything else.

Comment: @FabianRöling "but he doesn't become angry at all"

Comment: No creeper or potion, the Endermen was peacefull before i tried to look at him, like every Endermen

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Hm, maybe you're invisible? Or some client-server weirdness, did you leave and reopen the world/server since then and it still happens?

Comment: I lost the save since but i haven't tried to reopen

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is that the mobs search for entities within a 40 block radius(that is, most common mobs), but when they search for entities(like you), they only target entities within that 40 block range *and* in their field of view. If  you approach them from behind, they will not notice you until they 'hear' you, or turn around a look at you. 
When a mob 'hears' you, they are only picking up on sounds made by your movement, which is inconsistent. This can lead to some glitches concerning turning around to look at you. 
In recent updates, some mobs are 'afraid' of water, in the sense that they will not follow you into water greater than one block deep. This could cause them to not follow you. The complete passiveness is probably just a glitch caused by you getting into water.
With all non-ranged mobs, they don't attack until they are right by you. If you are more than one block away from them, they can not attack you, but they will try to get closer. When you saw the endermen in third-person, it is possible that you were just to far away. The passiveness is probably just a glitch.
Hope this helps!

Comment: It not really helps appart the glitch part, the rest doesn't concern my case ahah